# can i set all textviews to marquee?

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, marquee

I have 6 textviews and I want them to marquee all at the same time

```
 <TextView
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

 <TextView
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

is it possible?

**Code**

```
TextView txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(r.id.TextView2)
txt2.setSelected(true);
```

but it always crashes my app

Comment: Just put these parameters in your TextView: `android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Comment: it works for only one textView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-
I hope it would help you out..... :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Hello World" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Testing!!!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Try This In your Activity**

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 Animation animationToLeft = new TranslateAnimation(400, -400, 0, 0);
        animationToLeft.setDuration(12000); 
        animationToLeft.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        animationToLeft.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

        Animation animationToRight = new TranslateAnimation(-400,400, 0, 0);
        animationToRight.setDuration(12000); 
        animationToRight.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        animationToRight.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);

        tv.setAnimation(animationToLeft);
        tv1.setAnimation(animationToRight);


        String textLeft = "Really Long Scrolling Text Goes Here.... ..... ............ .... ....";
        String textRight = "Testing";

        tv.setText(textLeft);
        tv1.setText(textRight);
}
```

Comment: only one is scrolling the other not scrolling

Comment: i also tested txt2.setSelected(true) but it crashes my application

Answer (score 0):

Test based on android SDK 2.3.3

1. TextViews layout as follows:

   ```
   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/txt1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:ellipsize="marquee"
   android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:text="I have 6 textviews and I want them to marquee all at the same time"     />
   ```
2. set attributes for each textview:

   ```
   TextView txt1 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
   txt1.setSelected(true);
   txt1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
   ... ...
   ```